# Is there any virtual container-like plugin can turn IE into chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, containers

All:

I wonder if there is any plugin or something work as a virtual container can turn IE into Chrome environment?  Just like running applet across browsers?

If no way to do this, can any one suggest some light weight solution to build an VM image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome team used to support a utility called [Chrome Frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_Frame), but this was during a time when nearly all major IE versions had poor support for HTML5 and "CSS3".

The utility is [no longer supported](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html):

> [In 2009] many people were using browsers that lagged behind the leading edge...
>
> Today, most people are using modern browsers that support the majority
>   of the latest web technologies. Better yet, the usage of legacy
>   browsers is declining significantly and newer browsers stay up to date
>   automatically, which means the leading edge has become mainstream.
>
> Given these factors we’ve decided to retire Chrome Frame, and will cease support and updates for the product in January 2014.

I'm not sure what you mean by the second part of your question though, regarding the building of a virtual machine. Virtual machines of Internet Explorer are available for free though http://modern.ie.

Comment: Thanks, for the second solution, I am thinking that if it is hard to have IE turned into Chrome, then we just create a OS image which has chrome installed, the only thing I should consider if make this portable

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Right now, we have Data Viz application run in Chrome, but due to some reason, we move to a new environment which can not be able to use Chrome, only IE. The CSS and some JS work total different in IE, so that is why I am trying to find a way to turn IE into Chrome, otherwise, I may need to install a VM which run a OS image which create from my old environment

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: The current browser on the desktop is IE9, but I am not sure about that, other one told me

Comment: Modern versions of Windows, such as 7, 8, and 8.1, can all run Internet Explorer 11. I would encourage you to seek an upgrade; you shouldn't encounter many (if any) issues between Internet Explorer 11 and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, well, the thing is I can not decide which version I can install, it is decided by IT department.